# VOLTTRON reading data from multiple BACnet IP to MSTP Routers puts Building Management System down

Tags: volttron, bacnet

I have a BACnet network where multiple BACnet IP to MSTP routers are used.

The network configurations are as follows:

[Network Configuration sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1sZ1.jpg)

Now I am trying to read data from the network using Volttron. Previously no data was read, so I tried changing `use_read_multiple:false` in driver configurations. Still to make the request even smaller for the network I changed `max_per_request: 1`,

Now it is reading data but it shows an error after some time and puts the BMS down. This means we are not able to read or even discover devices on the BMS nor it gives data in VOLTTRON.

It gives an error on the router with most of AHUs, FCUs are attached. I tried testing just that Router (Say its identifier is 4900, now most of the devices like 4900:1, 4900:3, etc.) start giving an error on both BMS and my Laptop.

I have tried grouping too by making groups of 2-5 devices and setting "group_offset_interval" in Platform Driver configurations to some really high value to know whether it is a network congestion issue on the MSTP network. Sometime it starts working but after some time (an hour), it starts giving error on both sides BMS and VOLTTRON too. Although devices are ON.

It gives error on different Routers and sometimes many routers stop working.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in anticipation.

**Specifications:**

```
Volttron: 7.0

BACpypes: 0.16.7 (as required by Volttron for bacnet)
```

Comment: Looking forward to chatting tomorrow. Before the call, do you think you could provide the bacnet_proxy agent config, the platform_driver agent config, as well as a sample device config from the config store? Also, do you know the baudrate of the MSTP network segments beyond the routers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong here (in adding this to the mix) - but as it's relating to MSTP (- BACnet MS/TP), but you might want to also consider if there's a (half-typical) MSTP physical/wiring issue - might not necessarily be the software (or at least not alone).

(You might end up having to consider bifurcating the network / keep 'divide & conquer'ing it into small/2-halves segments to see/locate a wiring issue.)